# Redirect Console & Debug Output using the Roslyn Compiler

Tags: c#, .net, console, roslyn

If I have the following code using the Roslyn compiler to write to the console and debug output. How can I redirect the output, so that the Execute function can return both of them, as well as the actual result.

```
await Execute("System.Console.Write(\"Hello\"); System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(\"World\"););

public async Task<object> Execute(string code)
{
    return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(code);
}
```

Comment: You could parse & rewrite the calls to replace `Console` with your own functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `Console.SetOut` to change the stream that Console.Write* writes to. Then you can read it back once you're done running your code. Similarly, for Debug.Write, you can edit the `TraceListeners` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Once it is complied, it is code in your own process.

You could compile a full executable, save it to disk, and run it redirected.